# One-body density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator, second-quantization

We defined the one body-density in my lecture in the following way:
Let $\Psi \in D(\mathcal{N}^{1/2}) \cap \mathcal{F}_\pm(h)$ be normalised. The one-body density matrix of $\Psi$ is the unique operator bounded $\gamma_{\Psi}$ such that

\begin{equation}
    \langle f, \gamma_{\Psi} g \rangle = \langle \Psi, a^\dagger_\pm(g) a_\pm(f) \Psi \rangle
\end{equation}
where $a_\pm^\dagger$ and $a_\pm$ are the creation and annihilation operator restricted to the fermionic or bosonic fock space. I have heard of the density matrix in another class with a different definition:
Here the density matrix $\rho$ is

\begin{align}
\rho = \sum_j p_j |\psi_j\rangle \langle \psi_j|
\end{align}
for some states $|\psi_j\rangle$ and coefficients $p_j$.

What do the two definitions have to do with each other? For the second definition it would be easy for me to check, that the density matrix is a trace class operator which is positive definite, but how would i see this for the first definition?

How can I see from the first definition, that the following holds
\begin{align}
\text{tr}(\gamma_\Psi) = \langle\Psi, \mathcal{N}\Psi\rangle\, ,
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{N}$ is the number operator?

Comment: The left-hand side of your first identity is continuous in $f$ so that Riesz' lemma implies that the vector  $\gamma_\Psi g$ exists. Using the same identity is easy to se that changing $g$ we also have a continuous map. Hence the operator $\gamma_\Psi$ exists everywhere and is bounded. It is also positive by construction. To prove that it is trace class it is therefore sufficient to compute the trace with respect to a one-particle basis $\{f_n\}$. This trace is bounded by $||\Psi||^2$ by trivial manipulations involving the first identity.

Comment: The last identity arises form the intitial one and the definition of $N$ specialized to the basis $\{f_n\}$. I am too busy to insert details...I hope my suggestions help you to produces proofs.

Comment: (sorry, I evidently missed $\sqrt{N}$ in a norm: bounded by $||N^{1/2}\Psi||^2$.)

Comment: it helped a lot thank you very much!